# Можно ли без костылей узнать результат отработки магического метода __set?

Tags: ооп, php, классы

К сожалению, `__set` не возвращает ничего. Остается модифицировать сессию, левую переменную-флаг или плеваться исключениями. Что делают большие дяди в том случае, если присутствует медод `__set`, но изменять через него запрошенную переменную они не хотят, при этом не хотят и аварийно завершать всю систему?

Мне ближе именно исключения, но народ поговаривает, что они не самый лучший выход для корректировки нормального процесса, а if сюда прикручивается только через костыли.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С моей точки зрения, исключения -- естественный способ обработки ошибочных ситуаций в языках, которые достаточно хорошо их поддерживают. (Не знаю, относится ли это к php.) В [мануале](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) ошибочная ситуация обрабатывается через trigger_error.

Выброс исключения должен быть частью контракта, и пользователи класса должны быть готовы к такому повороту событий. (Пользу от обработки ошибок исключениями, думаю, вам не нужно объяснять.) Не дело класса думать, хочет ли он завершить обработку аварийно или нет; его дело -- отрапортовать ошибку исключением, а уж окружеющий код пусть решает, ловить это исключение или нет.

Другое дело, что инфраструктура окружающего кода должна соответствовать исключениям, и состояние программы не должно оставаться неопределённым. В C++ для такого традиционно используется идиома RAII, в C# -- using и блок finally.

Мне кажется, установка глобальной переменной при ошибках провоцирует плохой стиль.

Comment: Значит так и будем жить. В документации - описание исключений а кто не спрятался - ... =)

Comment: Документация рулит в любом случае. ;-) И вообще, пусть коллеги программируют правильно.